# How to get SCons StaticLibrary store the library file in another folder

Tags: static-libraries, scons

I'm using scons for a build project. I want to make a static library from object files that reside a different directory and surprisingly I'm not able to do that. Here is a snippet of the code I'm using:

```
OBJECT_FILES = env.Object('main.o', 'main.cpp')
env.StaticLibrary("../mylib", OBJECT_FILES)
```

StaticLibrary doesn't work if I put any directory above this directory even if I use absolute path. For the current directory or any other directory under the current directory, this works with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do that..

```
env.StaticLibrary("../${LIBPREFIX}mylib${LIBSUFFIX}", 'main.cpp')
```

No need to explicitly request `env.Object()` SCons will figure out the correct thing to do here.  Unless for some reason you want to later do something with that list of Object()'s.

When you specify

```
env.StaticLibrary("mylib", ['main.cpp'])
```

SCons will automatically prepend `$LIBPREFIX` and append `$LIBSUFFIX` to `mylib` and on a POSIX system you'd end up with `libmylib.a` on Windows you'd end up with `mylib.lib`
Please consider joining the SCons discord [server](https://discord.gg/bXVpWAy) for more "live" help and discussions.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. For clarification, I'm running scons on Ubuntu. I tried your suggestion and it's not working. I see a log of all the files being compiled but I don't see ```ar rc``` command being run. Why is this an issue is beyond me. Why doesn't scons execute static library when the path is not in the current directory or it's subdirs?

Comment: For now, I'm solving the problem by defining a "move" Command (scons Command) and put it in AlwaysBuild to move the created lib file to the appropriate folder. But I don't find this very ideal. Definitely appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: Comand not running is a separate issue.  The reason that's happening is only targets under the SConstruct dir are built by default. So if you want targets built elsewhere, you need to use Default("../${LIBPREFIX}mylib${LIBSUFFIX}") for the example above.

Comment: Maybe consider turning this around, so the library is in the current directory and you point to the other directory for sources?  e.g. something like `env.StaticLibrary("mylib", env.Glob('src/*.c'))`

Comment: @bdbaddog The object files are being built. ```ar rc``` command to create the library is not running which is I think part of your statement that "only targets under SConstruct dir are built by default"? I tried your suggestion and that didn't work unfortunately. I don't like my solution (moving the library file) either but it's working for now.

Comment: Thanks @MatsWichmann. This is a an established infrastructure with the input files checked in at certain locations. Can't change the directory structure for that matter (or the location of my sconstruct).

Comment: Well, my thinking wasn't to change the directory structure, just build scripts.  However, only you know your constraints. Also be aware of top-relative paths in SCons, those starting with a `#`, they are like absolute paths, but with the top directory being the directory of the SConstruct, not the top of the filesystem hierarchy.

Comment: Can you pastebin output when you say my suggestion didn’t work?